# ASP.net razor page checkbox not bound

Tags: c#, razor-pages

Trying to bind the checkboxes when I do a post. However, I'm probably overlooking something, as my list is always empty.

Here my code:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.CubeList)
        {
            <label name="" id="label_@item.CubeName" class="control-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="radio-inline" name="CubeList" id="@item.CubeName" />
                @item.CubeName
            </label>
        }
```

With this list I want to bind to:

```
    [BindProperty] public IList<CubeTableInDatabase> CubeList { get; set; }
```

In the class CubeTableInDatabase I currently only have one item:

```
  public class CubeTableInDatabase
  {
    [Key]
    public string? CubeName { get; set; }
  }
```

What I try is to have checkboxes for each item in the list of CubeList. And then on the post I want to check which one is checked and which one is not.
However, on my post action the CubeList is always empty (no matter what I select).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the explanations here:
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes#collections-of-complex-objects

You'll probably want to add another boolean property in your class, `IsSelected`:

```cs
public class CubeTableInDatabase
{
  [Key]
  public string? CubeName { get; set; }
    
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

And then have something like:

```
<input asp-for="item.IsSelected" /> @item.CubeName
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and link with explanations.